# How would a low-tech city look like?

Tags: science-based, society, ecology

I would like to imagine a city/society built only on Low-tech technologies. Those are the critters of this world:

- **Cheap options**, preferably things that can be found locally.
- **Easy to build** by people
- **Sustainable**, those technologies should be able to work for a long time without damaging the environment.
- **Self-sufficient**, everything should be found locally, like water and food for example.
- **Compact**, it should be as small as it's possible (on surface area)
- **No hierarchy**, the society should work with a minimum of authority and coercive power.

So my questions are, based on those critters, how would this society look like? And how would it be organized?

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Please explain why the hundreds of well-documented, well-studied and well-described ancient and medieval cities do not satisfy your curiosity, and in what way you want your city to be different. After all, they were built by people, sustainable (many endured for thousands of years), compact (very few of them were large). (1) "Cheap" is really, really unclear; what does it even mean? Cities are rarely if ever bought and sold, so I cannot get how you would set a price. (2) "No hierarchy" is surely something about the social structure, not about the city? (3) No city *ever* was self-sufficient...

Comment: Anyway, welcome to Wordbuilding SE! You may want to take the [tour] and peruse the [help], in order to become better acquainted with the goals and expectations of this site. In particular, fishing for ideas is not generally considered among the allowable uses of this site.

Comment: Snow I agree with AlexP but I have to think you know that human settlements were exactly as you describe for all but the most recent few hundred years of human history.  Many still are today in rural areas.  I feel like you are looking for something more or different.  Unpack what you envision a little more because I feel like there is the germ of something cool here,

Comment: @AlexP. (1) I mean, nothing high-tech. And should be able to be built quickly by individuals, so it should be kept simple. (2) I was unclear, when I was talking about the city, I was also talking about ways to manage that city (socially) (3) That's why I find interesting to imagine one :P

Comment: @Willk Could you explain what you mean by "human settlements"? From what I see on Wikipedia, this is very broad, any city is a human settlement.

Comment: @Snow  For "nothing high-tech" you can basically choose any technique used for any city prior to -- oh -- 1800.  That will put you before any useful effect from the Industrial Revolution.  Furthermore, the city will be heavily determined by climate and raw materials.  some places you gotta build in stone, others you can use sun-dried bricks, in others, wood.

Comment: @Snow - you are right about human settlements.  I meant it in the broadest sense so as not to fall into quibbling about what is and is not a city.    If your real question is about the governance of human settlements built with "primitive technology" you should edit your question.  As written now only your last bullet point is about governance and the first 5 are about the built infrastructure.

Comment: @Mary Yes, old stuff are interesting of course, but they don't fit all those criteria. But I sure want to use them as base.

Comment: @Willk Actually it concerns both.

Comment: We deal with single focused questions, one at a time, but you're welcome to write another question in it's own thread and link them.

Comment: @Draft 85 is right.  I think there are no votes to close on this question because it is cool.   There is no limit to how many you can ask except it gets annoying if you ask 10 on the same day.  Split your question into 2 (edit this one down to one and then post another) and put a link from one to the other.   Some people are into infrastructure and some into politics and you will get different answers.

Comment: No city ever was self-sufficient because self-sufficiency is not a design goal of cities. If you want self-sufficiency, then what is the purpose of having a city? It would only make your task so much harder. It you want self-sufficiency you want a village, you don't want to have to deal with problems such as food and water distribution, long travel time from the city to the cultivated fields etc.

Answer (score 2):

As commentors have said, look at pretty much any city prior to 1800 or so.

However, some of your requirements are going to be impossible to meet.  No hierachy?  Even villages have hierachies.  Why that's so is a better question for the Psychology site.

But the real problem is food.  You simply can't grow enough food for a city locally.  As Terry Pratchet put it (in "Night Watch"):

Every day maybe a hundred cows died for Ankh-Morpork. So did a flock of sheep and a herd of pigs, and the gods alone knew how many ducks, chickens, and geese. Flour? He'd heard it was eighty tons, and about the same amount of potatoes, and maybe twenty tons of herring. He didn't particularly want to know this kind of thing, but once you started having to sort out the everlasting traffic problem, these were the kind of facts that got handed to you.

Every day, forty thousand eggs were laid for the city. Every day, hundreds, thousands of carts and boats and barges converged on the city with fish and honey and oysters and olives and eels and lobsters. And then think of the horses dragging this stuff, and the windmills... and the wool coming in, too, every day, the cloth, the tobacco, the spices, the ore, the timber, the cheese, the coal, the fat, the tallow, the hay EVERY DAMN DAY...

[...]

It wasn't a city, it was a process, a weight on the world that distorted that land for hundred of miles around. People who'd never see it in their whole life nevertheless spent that life working for it. Thousands and thousands of green acres were part of it, forests were part of it. It drew in and consumed...